# setting up the environment for pipe2py

Tags: python, module, pipe, yahoo, pipeline

I am new to Yahoo! Pipes, and I have created a pipe which slightly alters yahoo rss feeds. I wanted to make this dynamic and perform this pipe on 2000 RSS feeds, and thus stumbled upon pipe2py (https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py). However, I do not understand the instructions to creating an environment to use pipe2py. I understand that I have to import a module for pipe2py, but everytime I follow the directions I am told "No module named pipe2py"

Has anyone encountered this problem, or now how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently added a `setup.py` file for pipe2py, so you should be able to:

```
python setup.py install
```

to install it into your Python environment.

Alternatively, you can download and install it directly using:

```
pip install pipe2py
```